Missing href attribute in links to documents in Wagtail
My Wagtail app (Wagtail 6.1) is configured to manage documents, and I want to include document links via a RichTextField of my page model. The output of the {{ page.body|richtext }} tag is missing a href attribute for document links:
<p data-block-key="c6hgq">
<a id="2" linktype="document">Document title</a>
</p>

I did not configure WAGTAILDOCS_SERVE_METHOD manually in the settings, so the serve_view method should be used according to the docs, but switching to WAGTAILDOCS_SERVE_METHOD = 'direct' does not fix the incomplete link quoted above.
What am I missing here?

It was a bug in Wagtail 6.1, fixed in 6.1.1:

Fix incorrect rich text to HTML conversion when multiple link / embed
types are present (Andy Chosak, Matt Westcott)

Sorry!
